# How to show a content of one website in another website?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website for example: https://test1.com, and a page on that website https://test1.com/show-content.

I want that page to display the content from another website, for example https://test2.com/show-different-content.

I know I can do it with PHP and file_get_contents, but I'm trying to do it with .htaccess, since I understand it can be possible. I've looked through all the SO questions I found regarding that, but I found no clear solution.

What I have tried in .htaccess is the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>=
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^show-content$ https://test2.com/show-different-content [P]
</IfModule>
```

What am I doing wrong? Or am trying to do something that is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options for this *if* the owner of that second site actually grants permission to proxy his sites content. You can use the proxy module available for the apache http server.

Either direct:

```
ProxyPass /show-content/ https://test2.com/show-different-content/
ProxyPassReverse /show-content/ https://test2.com/show-different-content/
```

Or embedded in the rewriting module:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?show-content/(.*)$ https://test2.com/show-different-content/$1 [P]
```

Obviously the proxy module needs to be loaded and activated inside the http server.